# Spring Security Authorization Server Jackson deserialization fails with custom principal

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-security, spring-authorization-server

I have created a Spring Boot 3 project with spring-boot-starter-security, spring-boot-starter-oauth2-authorization-server, spring-boot-starter-oauth2-client, etc.

I want to use a custom principal (to have a common interface to access things and avoid excessive casework) for users logged in normally to the authorization server and users logged in with an external oauth2 provider (e.g. googgle).

Toward this goal, I have defined a `MyPrincipal` class that implements both `UserDetails` and `OidcUser`.

```java
@JsonDeserialize
@JsonSerialize
@JsonIgnoreProperties(value = { "username", "name", "attributes", "claims", "userInfo",
        "idToken" }, ignoreUnknown = true)
public class MyPrincipal implements UserDetails, OidcUser {
    private long id;
    private String email;
    private String password;
    private Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> authorities;
    private boolean accountNonExpired, accountNonLocked, credentialsNonExpired, enabled;
    private String name;
    private Map<String, Object> attributes;
    private Map<String, Object> claims;
    private OidcUserInfo userInfo;
    private OidcIdToken idToken;

    public MyPrincipal() {}

    public MyPrincipal(OAuth2User oauth2User) {
        this.name = oauth2User.getName();
        this.attributes = oauth2User.getAttributes();
    }

    public MyPrincipal(OidcUser oidcUser) {
        this((OAuth2User) oidcUser);
        this.claims = oidcUser.getClaims();
        this.userInfo = oidcUser.getUserInfo();
        this.idToken = oidcUser.getIdToken();
    }

    @Override
    public Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> getAuthorities() {
        return authorities;
    }

    @Override
    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    @Override
    public String getUsername() {
        return email;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isAccountNonExpired() {
        return accountNonExpired;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isAccountNonLocked() {
        return accountNonLocked;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isCredentialsNonExpired() {
        return credentialsNonExpired;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isEnabled() {
        return enabled;
    }

    public long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    @Override
    public Map<String, Object> getAttributes() {
        return attributes;
    }

    @Override
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    @Override
    public Map<String, Object> getClaims() {
        return claims;
    }

    @Override
    public OidcUserInfo getUserInfo() {
        return userInfo;
    }

    @Override
    public OidcIdToken getIdToken() {
        return idToken;
    }
}
```

I am using `JdbcOAuth2AuthorizationService` to persist the oauth2 authorizations:

```java
@Bean
OAuth2AuthorizationService oauth2AuthorizationService(JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate,
        RegisteredClientRepository registeredClientRepository) {
    return new JdbcOAuth2AuthorizationService(jdbcTemplate, registeredClientRepository);
}
```

My 2 filter chains are like this:

```java
@Bean
@Order(Ordered.HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE)
SecurityFilterChain authorizationServerSecurityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    OAuth2AuthorizationServerConfiguration.applyDefaultSecurity(http);
    http.getConfigurer(OAuth2AuthorizationServerConfigurer.class).oidc(withDefaults());
    http.exceptionHandling(exceptions -> exceptions.defaultAuthenticationEntryPointFor(
            new LoginUrlAuthenticationEntryPoint("/login"), new MediaTypeRequestMatcher(MediaType.TEXT_HTML)))
            .oauth2ResourceServer(oauth2ResourceServer -> oauth2ResourceServer.jwt(withDefaults()));
    return http.build();
}
@Bean
SecurityFilterChain defaultSecurityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http.formLogin(withDefaults())
        .oauth2Login(oauth2Login ->
            oauth2Login.userInfoEndpoint(userInfoEndpoint ->
                userInfoEndpoint.userService(customOAuth2UserService).oidcUserService(customOidcUserService)
            )
        );
    return http.build();
}
```

I have a custom OidcUserService to return the custom `MyPrincipal` as the principal instead of the `DefaultOidcUser` so I can consistently access the additional fields in my user (as well as to persist the oauth2 user to the db).

```java
@Service
public class CustomOidcUserService implements OAuth2UserService<OidcUserRequest, OidcUser> {
    private final OidcUserService delegate = new OidcUserService();

    @Override
    @Transactional
    public OidcUser loadUser(OidcUserRequest userRequest) throws OAuth2AuthenticationException {
        var oidcUser = delegate.loadUser(userRequest);
        // saving user omitted...
        return new MyPrincipal(oidcUser);
    }
}
```

Now I get strange errors when trying to test login with Google like "Problem deserializing setterless property: no way to handle typed deser with setterless yet" (or similar). The error always points to a property that my `MyPrincipal` class DOESN'T ACTUALLY HAVE, such as "audience", "authenticationContextClass". I was very confused.

I checked the database and realized that this line in `JdbcOAuth2AuthorizationService`:

```java
String attributes = writeMap(authorization.getAttributes());
```

was causing Jackson to write out a whole bunch of unrelated fields into the JSON string, under the fields of my `MyPrincipal` (putting them at the same level as actual instance fields like "email", "id"), e.g. "expiresAt", "issuedAt", "nonce", "authenticationContextClass". Some of these fields seem to come from `OidcIdToken`'s Builder! I don't understand why this is happening. Is there some way to ignore these fields or fix it at the source?

Comment: Have you tried just implementing `OAuth2User` instead of `OidcUser`? You are free to design the user object however you wish as long as it implements the `OAuth2User` interface. I don't believe you *have to* have an `OidcUser`, unless you specifically need one. Also, have you tried registering a Jackson mixin for the `ObjectMapper` in `JdbcOAuth2AuthorizationService`?

Comment: @SteveRiesenberg Hi thanks for the comment. If I only implemented OAuth2User, the `customOAuth2UserService` doesn't get called when logging in with a provider that supports OpenID Connect. I have not registered a Jackson mixin, but I just feel that it's weird that properties that aren't even in my class are getting written by the objectmapper